# PostgreSQL's pg gem won't install on OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rubygems

I've looked all the solutions in the internet for this, reinstalled everything and still nothing... When i do gem install pg i get:

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>   ERROR:  Error installing pg:
>     ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
>   /Users/henriquedubugras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-pgsql->lib=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/lib --with-pg->config=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin/pg_config
> ```
>
> Using config values from /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/bin/pg_config
>   checking for libpq-fe.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
>   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
>   necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
>   details.  You may need configuration options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
>       --with-opt-dir
>       --with-opt-include
>       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>       --with-opt-lib
>       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>       --with-make-prog
>       --without-make-prog
>       --srcdir=.
>       --curdir
>       --ruby=/Users/henriquedubugras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
>       --with-pg
>       --without-pg
>       --with-pg-dir
>       --without-pg-dir
>       --with-pg-include
>       --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
>       --with-pg-lib
>       --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
>       --with-pg-config
>   /Users/henriquedubugras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
>   You have to install development tools first.
>       from /Users/henriquedubugras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in`try_cpp'
>       from /Users/henriquedubugras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:970:in `block in find_header'
>       from /Users/henriquedubugras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in`block in checking_for'
>       from /Users/henriquedubugras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
>       from /Users/henriquedubugras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in`open'
>       from /Users/henriquedubugras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
>       from /Users/henriquedubugras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in`open'
>       from /Users/henriquedubugras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
>       from /Users/henriquedubugras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in`checking_for'
>       from /Users/henriquedubugras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:969:in `find_header'
>       from extconf.rb:41:in`'
>
> Gem files will remain installed in /Users/henriquedubugras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.14.1 for inspection.
>   Results logged to /Users/henriquedubugras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.14.1/ext/gem_make.out

I tried setting the pg_config path, my xcode is installed, my command line tools from xcode is installed, my ruby version is 1.9.3 installed by RVM.

My mac is OS X Mountain Lion

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the Postgres client library header files (libpq-fe.h). In Debian the package is called libpq-dev. I don't know Mac packaging at all, but if there's no Mac respository building the PG client libs from source would work.

Answer (score -1):

i would recommend installing rvm https://rvm.io/rvm/install
then run rvm requirements. this will install all required packages, you're probably missing "gcc49" after this install rails and yore good to install postgres. i would suggest postgresapp or postgresql.